# Excluding recurring values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to not count the user multiple times, I only want to count it once. So even though the user is associated with multiple applications, I only want to count the user once and not 4 times.

Im working with Oracle Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

Table structure as follows:

```
Application | User
--------------------
Windows     |  James
Linux       |  James
AppleOS     |  James
Android     |  James
```

I've tried doing a distinct on the count but that did not seem to help.

```
select distinct b.application, b.user, count(distinct u.user) as count
from book b
where b.application IN ('Windows','Linux','AppleOS','Android')
group by b.application, b.user
```

What I am seeing

```
Application | User   |  Count
-----------------------------------
Windows     |  James |    1
Linux       |  James |    1
AppleOS     |  James |    1
Android     |  James |    1
```

What I'm expecting to see:

```
Application | User   |  Count
-----------------------------------
Windows     |  James |    1
Linux       |  James |
AppleOS     |  James | 
Android     |  James |
```

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? What version? please [edit] your question to include these details

Answer (score 0):

You can count one app for the user using `row_number()`:

```
select b.application, sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by user order by user) as seqnum
      from book b
      where b.application in ('Windows', 'Linux', 'AppleOS', 'Android')
     ) b
group by b.application;
```

This will choose an arbitrary row for the "1" value.  You can use the `order by` to be more specific, such as `order by b.application desc`.

Comment: To complement, if for instance you would want that any time that 'Windows' application is among the apps it should have count=1 then you can use a Case condition to enforce that rule, or perhaps have a priority list - Windows first, Linux second and so on, else use username alphabetically like this: order by case when application = 'Windows' then 1
                                                                     when application = 'Linux' then 2 end, user

Answer (score 0):

The most compact query is using the [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) analytic function to assign a unique sequence numbers to the applications within one user.

In a `CASE` statement you *counts only the rows with the number 1* - which guaranties that each User is counted exact once.

In the `ORDER BY` clause you define which application will be selected for the count (I'm using the alphabetical order of the applications).

```
select 
Application,
User_name,
case when row_number() over (partition by User_name order by Application) = 1
    then 1 end as cnt
from tab
;


APPLICA USER_        CNT
------- ----- ----------
Android James          1
AppleOS James           
Linux   James           
Windows James           
Android Bond           1
```